# VBA code dies when opening a Excel Workbook with macros

Tags: excel, vba

When runnign the following code, excel promts me about the document not beeing from a trusted source and if macros should be disabled. That is all fine and how it should be. It works fine when clicking on *enable macros* BUT if I click on *disable macros* the code just dies silently and never reaches "Made it". The same happens when i use `GetObject()` which was in the original code.

Is there a way to open the worksheet and disable the macros by default, not promting  the user? Or at least to somehow get the code to run again? I don't need them to run and it would be fine to just open the workbook read-only.

I know I can configure the Trust Center on my machine, but this ist for a company wide project, so thats not an option.

Also signing the code could maybe work?

```
Sub test()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim test As Workbook

    FileName = ".\hello.xlsm"
    Set test = Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True)

    MsgBox "Made it"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi,
In your Excel, click the File tab > Options.
On the left-side pane, select Trust Center, and then click Trust Center Settings…

In the left menu, select Macro Settings, choose Disable all macros without notification, and click OK. 
[link](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2020/03/11/enable-disable-macros-excel/)

Comment: Thank you, but I know how do do it localy on my machine, but I need this to work on all machines in my company without telling everyone they first have to change settings.

Comment: I don't think you can bypass that. That's a security setting after all.

Comment: I fell like automaticly choosing the secure way could be an option... But I guess its not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim test As Workbook

    FileName = ".\hello.xlsm"

    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityForceDisable
    Set test = Workbooks.Open(FileName, , True)
    Application.AutomationSecurity = msoAutomationSecurityByUI

    MsgBox "Made it"
End Sub
```

Comment: This looks promising. Thanks a lot. Will test tomorrow.

Comment: this seems to be excaly what I asked for. Thanks so much. Now I just have fix the rest of this terrible code.